# Javascript execute onkeyup function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following input in HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="siretNumber">Numéro de SIRET</label>
    <input onkeyup="checkSIRET(this);" onfocusout="ocr_on_fly(true, this, true)" onfocusin="ocr_on_fly(false, this, true);" type="text" class="form-control" id="siretNumber" value="{{ pdf['siret'] }}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="sirenNumber">Numéro de SIREN</label>
     <input onkeyup="checkSIREN(this)" onfocusout="ocr_on_fly(true, this, true)" onfocusin="ocr_on_fly(false, this, true)" type="text" class="form-control" id="sirenNumber" value="{{ pdf['siret'] }}">
</div>
```

On the `ocr_on_fly` function I need to automatically execute the function of the `onkeyup` attributes. With the following code I get the value of the `onkeyup` attr but how could I execute it then ?

```
let attr = input.getAttribute('onkeyup')
// attr = checkSIRET(this); or attr = checkSIREN(this);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dispatchEvent` to trigger the keyup [keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent).

```
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup'));
```

By triggering the event this way, the `this`-argument that you pass to your function matches what it would be during a normal `keyup` event.
If needed, you can pass a specific key that should be reported by the event:

```
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key':'a'}));
```

Comment: That's a nice solution also. The `'key':'a'` is a random argument to trigger the keyup event ?

Comment: @NathanCheval The key was indeed just a random one. It appears that that argument is optional, I've updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the name of the function as a string:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)